# Grafana - InfluxDB - SUM multiple series

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I try to sumerize my powerusage metrics from my smart plugs. They are present at influxdb in different series. I've tried to use wildcard in the "from"-Part by i cannot sumerize the results?! Is it even possible to add the different series and get a single result? I do not want to make 4 (or more) manual series, each for one plug to be flexible if new plugs comes to the system. Fyi, i've already tried a "sum" at the select statement

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Don't know why i did not tried this before. I add the transformation called "Add field from calculation" with mode set to "Reduce now" and calculation "Total".